# Classloading order in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, classloader

I'd like to know if the default behavior of JBoss server (4.2.3.GA in my case) is loading the classes in parent-first or parent-last mode.
And in case it work as I suspect in parent-last mode (i.e. first trying to load classes from the application's WEB-INF/lib and only if they are not found go to server\lib), how can I configure it to work in the opposite- first trying to load classes from outside and only looking inside the application afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set

```
java2ParentDelegation={false|true}
```

in your `jboss-app.xml` or `jboss-web.xml`. See [this article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration) for more information.

Comment: OK, but what is the default behavior of JBoss out-of-the-box? The article that you refered to, said that the class hierarchy is flat. so in case I have one class version in the app's WEN-INF\lib and another version of the same class in <JBoss-root>/server/default/lib than which one will be loaded?

Comment: according to the above article when using 'java2ParentDelegation=false' the order of loading will be: 1. WEB-INF/lib (for WARs) 2. libraries in server/default/lib 3. tomcat-libraries in server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat50.sar (jboss-3.2.6). So, when using 'java2ParentDelegation=true' than the order will be in the opposite direction??? let me know and I could mark an answer to this question