# Maven: wrong Hibernate version?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, jboss

I am encounting bug which is supposed to be fixed: `isMember on @ElementCollection throws QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree`

I googled about this issue and found ticket [HHH-5799](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5799) and [HHH-5209](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5209) where its claimed to be resolved in Hibernate 4.1.8, 4.3.0.Beta1.

I am trying to query for ProductType by one of its barcodes.

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class ProductType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> barcodes = new LinkedList<String>();

    ... getters+setters
}
```

I am using criteria api to query for product type by barcode using this code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ProductType> c = cb.createQuery(ProductType.class);
Root<ProductType> f = c.from(ProductType.class);
c.select(f).where(cb.isMember(barcode, f.get(ProductType_.barcodes)));
TypedQuery<ProductType> query = em.createQuery(c);
return query.getSingleResult();
```

I made a simple test:

```
@Test
public void testProductTypeWithMultipleBarcodes()
{
    ProductType type = new ProductType();
    List<String> barcodes = new LinkedList<String>();
    barcodes.add("1234561");
    barcodes.add("1234562");
    barcodes.add("1234563");
    type.setBarcodes(barcodes);
    em.persist(type);
    em.flush();

    assertEquals(type, productRepository.findProductTypeByBarcode("1234561"));
    assertEquals(type, productRepository.findProductTypeByBarcode("1234562"));
    assertEquals(type, productRepository.findProductTypeByBarcode("1234563"));
}
```

But I am getting org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException : unexpected end of subtree [select generatedAlias0 from cz.nuc.skladnik.storagecycle.product.ProductType as generatedAlias0 where :param0 member of generatedAlias0.barcodes] [Proxied because : Original exception not deserilizable, ClassNotFoundException]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.generate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:238)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:487)
```

Before exception I see:

```
00:40:44,965 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (http--0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0-8080-1) <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree: <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectClause(SqlGeneratorBase.java:490) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

mentioning `hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final`. So I've tried to add dependency on hibernate-core in my pom with no result:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Full pom.xml is here: http://pastebin.com/8U30fPpn

**I think that `hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final` is dragged in by some other dependency. Is this source of my problem? And if yes is there any way to find out what dependency is the black sheep?**

My container is JBoss 7.1.1 and I am using Arquillian for tests. As IDE I use IntelliJ Idea 13.

`mvn dependency:tree`: http://pastebin.com/k4YM1DpY

**UPDATE: I found out that hibernate 4.0.1 was dragged in by JBoss server itself. So I tried to ugrade Hibernate using this [Updating the Hibernate 4.x jars to a different Hibernate 4.x version](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.0.xjarswithanewerversion)**

However after doing this I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform`.

```
00:18:36,088 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] JBAS014612: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([]): java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014670: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.jpa
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:99) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:149) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:190) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:291) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:91) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.injectJtaManager(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.loadPersistenceAdapterModule(PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.java:112)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.subsystem.JPAExtension.initialize(JPAExtension.java:118)
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:88) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:127) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:113) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform from [Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @4e66ae7 (roots: d:\Programy\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
... 11 more
```

Comment: Yes, most likely dependency hell - are you using an IDE or similar tool?

Comment: Can you post your entire pom.xml?

Comment: I use IntelliJ but manually editting pom.xml based on JBoss tutorial. Entire pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/8U30fPpn

Comment: It would help if you posted the results of `mvn dependency:tree`…

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree`: http://pastebin.com/k4YM1DpY

Answer (score 1):

If you are somehow pulling in two `org.hibernate:hibernate-core` artifacts, dependency mediation should kick in and choose one. And there's no sign that you're pulling in two Hibernate artifacts with different coordinates from your `dependency:tree` output. So it sounds more like a misconfigured project than JAR hell per se, i.e. where you're pulling in conflicting libraries. If you want to be completely sure, though, check for duplicate files in your classpath using

```
mvn com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.4:check
```

which is a good [JAR hell plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin).

Your POM file and `dependency:tree` output is showing your JBoss and Hibernate versions as `RELEASE`. I don't know if that's a JBoss thing, but it's unclear to me what version `RELEASE` corresponds to. You should try specifying versions in your dependency management section and seeing if the problem persists, e.g.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

...

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This has the advantage that you fix the version of the dependency for your whole project, including transitive dependencies, instead of hoping dependency mediation picks the right one.

By the way, a simpler way to get what you need out of `dependency:tree` is to filter, in your case using

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=:*hibernate*::
```

Comment: This showed just hibernate specified in my pom.xml. But I found how older hibernate got involved. Check out my update in question.

Comment: That's now a different question, you might want to post it as such. There might be too much unrelated noise in this one, and it's now JBoss specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this command in the same directory as the pom.xml:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true -Dincludes=org.hibernate:hibernate-core
```

This will give you the dependency tree of not only the hibernate-core that was chosen, but other versions dependencies that altough present, where not chosen because some other dependency took precendence.

When in doubt which transitive dependency to choose, maven applies the following rules:

- the dependency that is the closest to the pom.xml project wins. for example if one version is two levels away in the tree and another 1 level away, the one 1 level away wins.
- if all dependencies are at the same level of distance from the pom.xml artifact, the one that shows up first on the pom wins.

The solution for this problem is to see with the comand above everyone that is requiring hibernate-core, decide which version you want and add the proper exclusions.

**EDIT:** The problem is that JBoss 7 is an EJB container that includes JPA, and the JPA on the server is interfering with the JPA on the WAR. This is because by default JBoss 7 works in 'server first' mode, where it will fetch libraries first from the server and only if they don't exist from the application.

You can change this to 'server last', where the jars on your application always take precedence. This can be done by setting `java2ParentDelegation=false` in file `jboss-app.xml` or `jboss-web.xml` - see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852613/classloading-order-in-jboss).

You can also turn off server modules one by one, but this is more error prone.

For that, create a file in `src/main/resources/META-INF` named `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, and there turn off the hibernate/JPA modules on the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
    <deployment>  
        <exclusions>  
            <module name="org.hibernate" /> 
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa" />
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" />
            ... 
       </exclusions>  
    </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: This showed just hibernate specified in my pom.xml. But I found how older hibernate got involved. Check out my update in question.

Comment: its seems it's a problem of libraries one the server interfering with libraries one the WAR, see an update above for two ways to turn off the libraries on the server, and use only the ones on the WAR

Comment: Unfortunally `java2ParentDelegation` is not available in JBoss 7.x. Now I am trying to avoid `ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform` using `<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>` with no success. However this is being off topic so I guess I will post a new question.